# Renaming multiples files from differernt directories using shell script

Tags: shell

I have 50 directories and inside each directory I have a file of the name hist_anh_abs_0. So I have 50 files of the

```
name hist_anh_abs_0
```

What I want is the following, I want to run a loop over all 50 directories and which will pull out the file name `hist_anh_abs_0` and rename it like `hist_anh_abs_0_1`, `hist_anh_abs_0_2`... and finally put all the renamed files in a separate directory.
I did something like this

for file in hist_anh_abs_0
do
    mv -i "${file}" "${file/-_abs_0-/-_abs_0_$i-}"
done

But I can't do the part where it will read all the directories and look for the file of name hist_anh_abs_0

Comment: How do we know which file to be numbered as what? The number matters? or not?

Comment: no. It doesn't matter

Comment: Did you make an attempt at all? solving it? We can help you out if you faced issues doing it

Comment: for file in hist_anh_abs_0
do
    mv -i "${file}" "${file/-abs_0-/-abs_0_$i-}"
done

Comment: But i can't do th first part where it will read all dirs and look for the file hist_anh_abs_0

Comment: Refer my answer and see if it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ct=0 ;
for f in */hist_anh_abs_0 
do 
  mv $f ${destdir}/${f}_$((ct++));
done
```

Comment: Thanks Tim. But when you are writing ct=0 for f in */hist_anh_abs_0 whether the program will read all 50 dirs and pull out the file name 'hist_anh_abs_0'?

Comment: That's the */ in the list of the for statement, assuming this is executed from the directory that is the parent of the 50 directories.   Also need to set destdir, but it wasn't clear where you wanted that destination directory to be.

Comment: but if i run the script it is telling mv: cannot move 'Quantas_10000_561_638/hist_anh_abs_0' to 'HIS_ANH_ABS_0/Quantas_10000_561_638/hist_anh_abs_0_29': No such file or directory and I am getting error for all files.

Comment: Ah, I missed one bit.  We need to take the basename of $f to strip off the directory part.   Try this:

    ct=0 ;
    for f in */hist_anh_abs_0 
    do 
        mv $f ${destdir}/`basename $f`_$((ct++));
    done

Comment: That basename part should be in backquotes.   Sorry, I'm a noob at stackoverflow so I haven't got the markup figured out yet.

Comment: ct=0 ; for f in */hist_anh_abs_0 do mv $f ${destdir}/\`basename $f\`_$((ct++)); done

Comment: what is the base name here? I'm little confused

Comment: basename is a command in UNIX/linux that returns just the base name (file name without any leading directory names) of its argument.    Type "man basename" to get the info.